# Facebook JS API acts differently with different appid's

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm building a web application and I need to connect it with facebook. My final goal is to post picture to users wall and album but I've hit brick wall.

When using my own `app_id` (my own, I mean I created this 'test' application with my own facebook account) it works perfectly -- picture is posted on users wall and album. But when using clients `app_id` (client created this application with their own account, I'm listed there as developer) it acts differently -- no picture is posted on users wall.

I've checked the settings, they are same. Code, same. Response I get from facebook when posting picture - different.

Here's code I'm using:

```
<button>share photo</button>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
var graph_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token=';
var photo_url = '<?php echo $photo_url; ?>';
var user_id = null;
var access_token = null;

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    // init the FB JS SDK
    FB.init({
        appId      : '<?php echo $app_id; ?>',                        // App ID from the app dashboard
        channelUrl : '//my-website/channel.php', // Channel file for x-domain comms
        status     : true,                                 // Check Facebook Login status
        xfbml      : true                                  // Look for social plugins on the page
    });

    // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            user_id = response.authResponse.userID;
            access_token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
            // nothing to do
        } else {
            FB.login(function(response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    user_id = response.authResponse.userID;
                    access_token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                }
            });
        }
    });

    $('button').on('click', function(ev) {
        if (user_id && access_token) {
            FB.api('/me/photos', 'post', {
                url: photo_url,
                message: 'dasdad',
                access_token: access_token
            }, function(response) {
                console.log(response); // <---- this different
            });
        }
    });
};

// Load the SDK asynchronously
(function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

This code logs either `id` and `post_id` (with my `app_id`, like it should) or just `id` (with client `app_id`). I'm completely lost here, can anyone point me to right direction? What am I doing wrong here? Is this bug on facebook side?

Comment: I’m not seeing you ask for any permissions when you do the login – so I assume your app might still have that permission because you gave it earlier, but the other app does not have it. Please log the access token to your browser console for both apps, and then check it here https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: Thank You! This was it! Could You also add this as answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not seeing you ask for any permissions when you do the login – so I assume your app might still have that permission because you gave it earlier, but the other app does not have it.

Please log the access token to your browser console for both apps, and then check it here https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug